Deities and mantras to control our mind?
The situation of my mind is that , if want to do something I am getting swayed by other things. I know my objective is important but still unable to do it for some mental reasons . To me my mind has become my worst enemy. How can I control the mind to such a state that it not only obeys my will , but provides me with right ideas at the right time ? Are there any deities who is associated with this mind? And are there any mantras to give peace and stability to the mind? Thank you.

Hare Krishna Maha Mantra can be chanted by anyone at any time. To advance swiftly i.e., achieve mind control as well as spiritual bliss would require taking to take to a sattvic lifestyle (waking up early, eating healthy after offering to Krishna who is the deity of the Mantra, etc.). If there're specific questions, feel free to ask.
